# PHP Sessions Self-Destroyed / Timeout at Random Times

Tags: php, apache, session, session-cookies

I am having SESSION problem even though I have the following settings on my Apache based server:

```
MY PHP INI Settings:
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_maxlifetime = 6628000
session.cookie_lifetime = 6628000
session.cache_expire = 177600
```

When does the session expire?

1. At random times
2. When there is heavy server traffic, heavy POST and GET operations, all or some users

**I am not sure if my problem is PHP based or related to Apache settings. I'm open to suggestions for solutions.**

I checked the PHP settings but I think my problem is not based on PHP Settings.

Comment: Are you using your "own" `session.save_path`, or are you perhaps sharing one with other users/applications on the same machine ...?

Comment: @CBroe  `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"`. Just one app

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically your sessions will expire after 6628000 seconds, but since PHP session files are just normal files, and PHP session is implemented through cookies, there are other reasons that can cause a session to be unavailable.

- The client cookie is deleted by the browser.
- The session file is deleted by some cron jobs.

So the answer usually is at random times.

If you faced a session expiration problem, you can check if the cookie and the session file still exist.